# mysqli real_escape_string problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

When im inserting to the database on my dev server the text goes in fine, for example "that's" is "that's" in the db.

when uploading the exact same code to production server (hosted on a reseller account at bluehost) "that's" becomes "that\'s",

im not double escaping, its exactly the same code, what could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you using same database and database settings for both Development & Production?

Answer (score 1):

The production server probably has [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled. See the page about disabling it for various options to fix it.